# program does not recognize the number in the number input

Tags: javascript, html, numbers

I need your help :-)

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Der Einmaleins - Trainer</title>  
 <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
 <!--<script src = "script1m1.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Der Einmaleins - Trainer</h1> 
 <button type="button" onclick = "start();">Start</button> 
 <!--<button type = "button" onclick = "fertig();">Fertig!</button>-->
 <input id = "erginput" type = "number"  >

 <!--<label id = "rn1"></label>  
 <label id = "multiplication"></label>
 <label id = "rn2"></label>  
 <br>-->
 <label id = "feedback"></label>


 </body>
 <script>
 function start(){
  var ergebnis = document.getElementById("erginput").innerHTML;  
  document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = ergebnis;
 }
 </script>
 </html>
```

The problem: When I set a number in the number input and click on start, the number is not shown.

Thanks in advance !

Ji W

Comment: Reading [the documetation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)  is always useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` elements don't have `innerHTML`, they have `value`, so:

```
function start(){
    var ergebnis = document.getElementById("erginput").value;
    // Note -------------------------------------------^^^^^
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = ergebnis;
}
```

(`label` elements *do* have `innerHTML`, which is why there's only one change above.)